# Count query with timestamp value

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I would like to create a count query (in Postgres) which counts `data.data_name` dependent on `data.todb_date`.

So what I want to is that the query counts all the rows that are higher than the requirement in the `WHERE` clause. I tried `Count(data.data_name)` and `Count(*)` but they didn't work.

My planned result looks like this:

```
todb_date: 2016-01-01 
data.data_name : test1
count: 150

todb_date: 2017-01-01 
data.data_name : test1
count: 130
```

This is the query I have tried:

```
SELECT data.data_name, parentdata.data_id, 
       data.data_id, parentdata.todb_date, 
       COUNT (data.data_name) 
FROM parentdata, data 
WHERE parentdata.data_id = data.data_id 
  AND parentdata.todb_date > '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY parentdata.data_id, data.data_id, data.data_name, parentdata.todb_date
```

Comment: If your `data_id` field is a unique/primary key, do not need the other fields from that table in `GROUP BY`... Also, remove `data.data_id` from result and `GROUP BY`...

Comment: If you want to `GROUP BY` date values from timestamps, add `CAST(parentdata.todb_date AS DATE)`, or [`DATE_TRUNC('day', parentdata.todb_date)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Usagi Miyamoto suggested, you should use a `data_trunc()` function to group your results according to certain time increments (here: per year):

```
SELECT d.data_name nam, date_trunc('year',p.todb_date) yr, COUNT(*) cnt 
FROM parentdata p 
INNER JOIN data d ON p.data_id = d.data_id AND p.todb_date > '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY d.data_name,date_trunc('year',p.todb_date)
ORDER BY nam, yr
```

If you replace `'year'` by `'date'` you will get daily counts, see [here](https://rextester.com/CBGIH84973).